# when / how often to use Chai-as-promised's .notify()

Tags: testing, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

We are using Chai-as-promised with protractor and cucumberjs. I have a question about the .notify(callback) method in the chai-as-promised library.

If we are running multiple scenarios with a few steps in each.  Should notify() be called at the end of each step?

So

```
Scenario 1
  Step 1 Expect(promise).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
  Step 2 Expect(promise2).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
Scenario 2
  Step 3 Expect(promise3).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
  Step 4 Expect(promise4).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
```

I always though we should only have the 'and.notify(callback)' in the last step.

So

```
Scenario 1
  Step 1 Expect(promise).to.eventually.to.equal(true);
  Step 2 Expect(promise2).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
Scenario 2
  Step 3 Expect(promise3).to.eventually.to.equal(true);
  Step 4 Expect(promise4).to.eventually.to.equal(true).and.notify(callback);
```

I have a similar question over at the github page. 
https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/65

Answer (score 1):

Prior to `CucumberJS` `v0.5.0`, all Step Definitions needed to be defined with a `callback` argument that needed to be called once the step was finished executing.

In `v0.5.0`, they updated the library so that the `callback` argument was no longer necessary. From their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/9cc2f801f126110d0ce42dc59c43ed726d92d59a/CHANGELOG.md#v050):

> New features
>
> - Support promises from step definitions (Will Farrell)
> - Support synchronous step definitions (Julien Biezemans)

While the return value from `chai-as-promised` assertions [aren't real promises](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/tree/c0d887605a6df879d7ff1700600ad450e6e09a84#customizing-output-promises), their interface is similar enough for `CucumberJS` to treat them like promises. So, to answer your question:

- Prior to `CucumberJS` `v0.5.0`, you have to call `notify()` at the end of each step.
- After `CucumberJS` `v0.5.0`, you do not have to call `notify()` at the end of any step.